# Can someone explain details of hybris auditing system?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

By Default hybris auditing system comes in picture whenever any change in model or any attribute.
I want to use Hybris auditing module in my application?(SavedValuesModel).Does this module has any issue in use? does this work under the same transaction model.?  I am newbie for hybris. Please provide some details on this.

Answer (score 2):

Hybris auditing system comes with the item *SavedValues*. this is the item which maintains the model value history in it. Please refer to the item type declaration below:

```
 <!-- hmc legacy - Saved Values -->
        <itemtype code="SavedValues"
                  generate="true"
                  jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.hmc.jalo.SavedValues"
                  extends="GenericItem"
                  autocreate="true">
            <deployment table="SavedValues" typecode="334"/>
            <attributes>
            .
            .
            .
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
```

Now this item has a 1-n relation with the SavedValueEntry,

```
<!-- hmc legacy - Saved values -->
        <relation code="SavedValueEntriesRelation" autocreate="true" generate="true" localized="false">
            <sourceElement type="SavedValues" qualifier="parent" cardinality="one">
                <modifiers read="true" write="false" initial="true" optional="false" search="true"/>
            </sourceElement>

            <targetElement type="SavedValueEntry" qualifier="savedValuesEntries" cardinality="many"
                           collectiontype="set">
                <modifiers read="true" write="false" optional="true" partof="true"></modifiers>
            </targetElement>
        </relation>
```

This item type contains the original and changed values of the item, along with the other details such as modification type (create/update/remove), the user doing the change etc.

The main disadvantages of this system are mentioned below:

1. Any changes done to the item type outside hmc (e.g. by impex etc.) are not recorded. However, if the changes need to be logged then one can use the below syntax

   HMCManager.getInstance().logItemModification(item.getPk(), newValues, oldValues, false);
2. This audit trail has a performance overhead and needs to be cleaned up for performance tune ups.

You can follow the below references for further reading:

1. https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/SavedValues+-+Keeping+Track+of+Attribute+Value+Modification
2. https://experts.hybris.com/questions/9332/logging-to-savedvalues-table.html